# Django URL не видит slug

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Django не видит slug при том что он есть.

main - urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^uk/', include('ukrainian.urls')),
    url(r'^en/', include('english.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('russian.urls')),

]
```

ukrainian.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import  PostDetailView,  PagesDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='ukrainian/index.html')),
    # url(r'^posts/$', PostListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PostDetailView.as_view()),
    # url(r'^pages/$', PagesListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PagesDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

english.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import  PostDetailView,  PagesDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='english/index.html')),
    # url(r'^posts/$', PostListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PostDetailView.as_view()),
    # url(r'^pages/$', PagesListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PagesDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

russian.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import  PostDetailView,  PagesDetailView, PagesListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='russian/index.html')),
    # url(r'^posts/$', PostListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^pages/$', PagesListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PostDetailView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PagesDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

У страниц и постов уникальные slug, но когда я пытаюсь получить страницы

> "GET /vopros-otvet HTTP/1.0" 404 1784

Comment: какой url запрашиваете? я подозреваю что просто забыли страну дописать: `/uk/vopros-otvet`. Ах да, и `-` в `[\w-]` надо экранировать тоже: `[\w\-]`

Comment: Спасибо, но дело оказалось в другом. Django не хочет искать в двух разных модулях, а вот если использовать только одну вьюху всё норм